# Uploading documents to Watson Discovery through API

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

From the documentation listed [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/discovery?topic=discovery-addcontent) there is a limit of **50MB** per file.

Does this counts also the case, when we get a JSON data through the API, or it is only for the case when we upload documents with the `Discovery Tooling`?

And if it does, how can we proceed a JSON data from an API when the data is more than 50MB?

Answer (score 0):

The 50MB file size limit applies to all data formats including json. I would expect to see an error response from the API if you send json data of greater size than 50MB.

if your data is more than 50MB, then you will need to either truncate or split it.

Comment: Okay, but what for the cases when we want to pass a knowledge base to Discovery. This knowledge base may be 1Gb or 10Gb etc. How can we then process this data, so Discovery can use it? (Even with IBM Cloud Object Storage[link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/discovery-data?topic=discovery-data-sources) there is a limitation)

Comment: that is a different question.

Comment: Just to mention: Even with 10MB JSON data, the API does not process it. Where do these 50Mb file size apply for?

Comment: What is the error response for the 10MB json data ?

Comment: The error is: **Request Entity Too Large: The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed file size** It happens even with 4Mb JSON data ...

Comment: That is really strange. Are you sure that it is the Watson service that is throwing that error? How are you invoking the service? - through cURL or an app ? Is your request going through a proxy?

Comment: I'm invoking this through ```Node.Js``` backend and even have set the **request payload limit** to 50Mb. Not sure whether it goes through a proxy.